# How to click on a ui-sref link in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor and I wanted to know how to use ui-sref state to test. I tried using "by.linkUiSref" but it gave me error : by.linkUiSref is not a function

Comment: Please provide more detail. HTML / screenshot / code whatever you can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library for this.

See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-uisref-locator

Comment: Perfect. Worked.. Thank you.